# Flink two different packages for ProcessWindowFunction

Tags: scala, apache-flink, window-functions

## Question

What is the difference of ProcessWindowFunction in different packages and where/when to use which one of them?

- org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessWindowFunction
- org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.ProcessWindowFunction

For Window Operations, as in [Apache Flink: ProcessWindowFunction implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548308/apache-flink-processwindowfunction-implementation),  **org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala** is the correct one to use, but could not find the Flink 1.8 API documentation, only found  for 1.3.

- [Uses of Class org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.ProcessAllWindowFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/index.html?org/apache/flink/streaming/api/scala/function/class-use/ProcessAllWindowFunction.html)

If I use **org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessWindowFunction**, get the error.

```
Error:(66, 20) type mismatch;
 found   : com.dataartisans.flinktraining.exercises.datastream_scala.windows.HourlyTipProcessFunction
 required: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.ProcessWindowFunction[com.dataartisans.flinktraining.exercises.datastream_java.datatypes.TaxiFare,?,org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple,org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.windows.TimeWindow]
          .process(new HourlyTipProcessFunction())
```

### Environment

Ubuntu

VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.19</slf4j.version>
    <flink.version>1.8.0</flink.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 3):

org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.windowing.ProcessWindowFunction is the Java API class for ProcessWindowFunctions on KeyedStreams.

org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.function.ProcessWindowFunction is the same, but for the Scala API.

ProcessAllWindowFunctions are for windows on non-keyed streams.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wonder why having two different classes where Scala can use Java class.

Comment: Effort has been made to create a more fluent API for Scala.